# My HP Pavilion dv6700 won't switch on at all. Can anyone help please?

Tags: laptop, power, hp-pavilion

I have an HP Pavilion dv6700. Only recently when I try to turn it on by pressing the power button the lights glow for about one second and turn off. I tried all otions removing battery and trying with direct AC line, that didn't work. I thought I have to reseat my RAM so I did that by removing the module but that still didn't work.

I have lots of stuff in it. My warranty is over so I have to pay $395 if I have to send it to HP for repair.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can try removing the hard drive, and CD/DVD drive, just to rule those out.  If it still gives the same results, it is most likely a problem with the motherboard.

To be honest, if it's the motherboard, it is probably not worth fixing.  Take your $395, and put it toward getting a new computer.  Also, get a USB hard drive enclosure.  Then, put the old hard drive in the enclosure, and connect it to your new computer, and you should be able to copy all your files off of it.  Then, you can format the old drive, and use it as a backup/portable media drive.

Answer (score 2):

My DV6-2300 recently had similar problems.  Before you do either of the above, do a hardware reset.  (On the dv-6) you do so by removing both the power adapter and the battery then holding the power button down for ~15 seconds (I heard a slight click after 10 seconds).  Then reinsert the battery AND power adapter.  If you still don't get any activity then you might want to try one of the previous answers.

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Remove all cables from the motherboard except for the ones from the power supply and the cable to the front on/off buttons. Remove all ram. Try to boot. If you get any screen at all, that is further than before and there may be hope for your mobo.

If you did get a screen, start putting stuff back on gradually 'til you find what the problem is.

If you did not get anywhere with the above, you'll need to rule out the power supply. If you can borrow one from someone else just for testing purposes, great. If you have a multimeter, you can test the voltages coming to the mobo according to the pinout found [here](http://www.duxcw.com/faq/ps/ps4.htm) or elsewhere (just search "atx power supply pinout". If a different PS works or the voltage test fails, your fixed by simply buying a new power supply.

If the PS is not the root cause, you can do as pkaeding suggests and just recover your data. Another option (if you really want to keep your system as it was) would be to find the p/n on your mobo and see if you can find one on Ebay. It would depend on how much you want it back and how long your willing to wait. The ebay option would be way cheaper than dropping $400 on a new system.

Comment: You won't get anything on your screen if you're pulling the RAM.

Comment: You will get the bios dummy!

Comment: I stand corrected. You must have at least one stick installed. Good catch Brad. Sorry for the flame.